# ScrollView with GridLayout vs. ScrollView with BoxLayout, Kivy

Tags: python, kivy

So, I'm working with ScrollView. ScrollView requires a constant minimum_height that doesn't shrink to the size of the window or element. To do that, we set the minimum_height of its child, the layout the ScrollView holds, to the total height of the layout itself. I suppose, this:

1. makes it immune to resizing, and
2. means that the height/size
   variable is not omnipotent, and is overridden by outer layout
   sizes/windows.

That's fine. The question I have, though, **what is the difference between GridLayouts and BoxLayouts?** inclement from SO says:

'The BoxLayout is designed to make its children fill itself. A better layout for the dynamic resizing you want is the GridLayout, which has a minimum_height you can bind to for automatic resizing.'

(Source: [kivy scrollview with boxlayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31367853/kivy-scrollview-with-boxlayout))

Maybe there's something with the wording, but:

1. *GridLayouts also fills itself with children (haha)*
2. Both the GridLayout and BoxLayout documentation show a read_only attribute of minimum_height.

And, according my hypothesis, *if the minimum_height is high enough, the BoxLayout should fill itself in exactly the same way GridLayout does*. But, the minimum_height isn't changed like the GridLayout's is, so that means:

1. The minimum_height being 'read only' for GridLayout is a 'lie' (ha, it is--we changed it)
2. The minimum_height attribute may still be usable, but is accessed differently for BoxLayout
3. BoxLayout simply has no minimum_height, and is always subject to its outer containers.

But then, if we accept #3, then there's the observation that:

1. My ScrollView is nested in a BoxLayout root that's the entire screen (~750dp high)
2. When my ScrollView is set anywhere from 200-800:
3. *There's no change to the BoxLayout child the ScrollView holds. My ScrollView shows the same two, unscrollable buttons (presumably with all the other 97 buttons stacked directly behind it) at ~250dp height*

So, even if BoxLayout has no minimum_height, there's something else going on.

But I'm worried that'll get us off track. So, basically, **I'm wondering what prevents the BoxLayout from having a minimum_height attribute--that we can set like GridLayout.**